# Javascript/HTML5 Game dev - Implementing a simple jump. Works first time, not after

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

This works like a charm the first time it is triggered. But after that it just increases the playerYPos by 8 ever time it is triggered. I have tried everything I can think of, but can't seem to figure out why.

```
var playerYPos = 188;
var playerJumpSpeed = 8;
var playerJumpVelocity = playerJumpSpeed;

function jump(){
    playerYPos -= playerJumpVelocity;

    //Hits top
    if(playerYPos < 40){
        playerJumpVelocity = -playerJumpSpeed;
    }
    if(playerYPos >= 188){
        keyW = false;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? How are you triggering the jump?

Answer (score 0):

Is it because the `playerJumpVelocity` variable is not being reset the next time the function is called? I.e:

```
function jump()
{
    var playerJumpVelocity = playerJumpSpeed;
    playerYPos -= playerJumpVelocity;

    //Hits top
    if(playerYPos < 40){
        playerJumpVelocity = -playerJumpSpeed;
    }
    if(playerYPos >= 188){
        keyW = false;
    }
}
```